# How Get some specific value from Rails string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I want to get some specific value from string of Rails like below these are two string.

```
 1. "http://localhost:3000/admin/shops/assign_shoes?id=50&page=1"

 2. "http://localhost:3000/admin/shops/assign_shoes?id=50"
```

I always need value of "id" which is "50". Don't matter how many parameters are in string

as query string.

Actually these strings are values of **request.referer**

Any efficient method?

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: I want to get value of id. which is 50 in both strings.

Comment: id = 50 see it is in query string.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying your controller (for example) is being passed a string of a URL, and you need to parse out the query parameters? Or are you talking about how to get parameters in a normal HTTP GET request?

Comment: @Teeg yes you are right.

Comment: @Kashiftufail ...which one am I right about? I posed two different scenarios.

Comment: @Teeg i just want to get value of id after parse these mentioned strings.

Comment: @AbM these are not params. This is string.

Comment: @Kashiftufail Ok, your update makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to do this, the common way I know about is parsing the string using the [`URI` class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html), and making use of the [`CGI` class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html) to extract the query params, like so:

```
uri = URI.parse(request.referer)
parsed_query = CGI::parse(uri.query).symbolize_keys
id_value = parsed_query[:id].first
```

Note the `.first`, as the values of the query params are resolved to arrays. Additionally, the keys are parsed in to strings, therefore I would include `symbolize_keys` for convenience and consistency.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one of the ways:

```
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'

uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/admin/shops/assign_shoes?id=50&page=1")
# => #<URI::HTTP:0x000001018dc5c8 URL:http://localhost:3000/admin/shops/assign_shoes?id=50&page=1> 

uri_params = CGI.parse(uri.query)
# => {"id"=>["50"], "page"=>["1"]} 

uri_params["id"].first #=> "50" - NOTE: this will be a String!!
```

However, I'd prefer the answer which uses regular expressions.

Comment: Beat me to it. Just a quick note, in my test I did not have to `require 'cgi'` in rails, which is what the OP appears to be using. It seems the module is already included, I believe.

Comment: Aah, I did it in irb. So, had to require both `uri` and `cgi`. :/

Comment: Makes sense. That's what I figured.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions.

```
id = /\/admin\/shops\/assign_shoes\?id=(\d+)/.match(request.referer)[1]
```

Comment: I would NOT use regular expressions to parse URLs, because there are perfectly good URL parsers already available to every Rails application (`Rack::Utils`), and the regular expression will be more brittle. For example, you don't really care about the path, but if you change it, your regular expression will break. It will also be difficult to make a regular expression that accepts the `id` parameter at any position.

Comment: I agree that it is better to use the URL parsers.